# Is there a way to find out the list of users who logged into an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to find out the list of users who logged into a Linux EC2 instance (e.g IP, time ..) for audit purposes.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know what operating system this is, would you?

Comment: Could you provide some more details to your question about what your requirements are? Do you want historical logon info? Only active connections? etc.

Comment: Looks like this is on its way to being closed due to lack of information. I'd suggest editing your question to include more info on the operating system(s) involved. If the question has already been closed by that point, you can flag it and request that it be re-opened.

Comment: historical info not necessarily active connections

Comment: @ErikA - I had mentioned that this was for a Linux instance, wasn't that clear to you? Its just weird that someone would mark this as closed :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is a linux instance, the `w` shell commmand will show users that are currently logged in.

To see the last time someone logged in, use the `lastlog` command.

If you want a full accounting of all user logins, you'll need to grep through `/var/log/auth.log`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `last`

Also, `man last`, `man whois`, `man who`

This all assumes you're talking about UNIX interactive logons at the OS level.  If you're talking about anything else (like application logons, management console logons, you'll need to be more specific).